$f(n)$ is the number of groups of order $n$. Prove $n \cdot f(n)$ is not injective.
$f(n)$ is the number of groups of order n up to isomorphism.
Prove $n \cdot f(n)$ is not an injective function without brute force search.
The domain is the set of nonnegative integers.
Progress: I already solve this problem. Just sharing the solution.
Motivation: I am studing $f(n)$ nowadays. Nobody knows how to efficiently find the number of groups in general. I'm trying to find some interesting properties about this.
$f(n)$ is not an injective function. It's trivial to prove this. I also find counterexamples for $n \cdot f(n)$, $n^{2} \cdot f(n)$ and $n^{3} \cdot f(n)$. I think the most natural thinking is: Is $n^{b} \cdot f(n)$ not injective for every positive integer $b$? It looks like a very hard question. I am not good enough to solve this, but I expected to do it this in the future.
I have some problems related to injective functions. I used known values to brute force search counterexemples. But it has a problem. My datasets have finite size.
We already know precise formulas for $f(n)$ for some configurations of prime factoring. This can be used to give us stronger information about our function.
So I posted this question here. Some people commented. I tried hard (in ten hours) a lot of possibilities for $$a \cdot f(a) = b \cdot f(b)$$ I think there is no examples if $a \cdot f(a)$ has less than 4 primes, I found contradictions for every possibilities.
And finally, I found a set of numbers that solve the problem. After this, using Dirichlet Theorem (1837), I discoved that the set had infinite size.
This last discovery was amazing for me. I didn't expected that I could prove this.

Obvious start is to compute examples for small $n$.

The list at the OEIS page already gives two pairs of inputs with the same output: $(18, 45)$ and $(42, 63)$. Is your proof more elegant than this? In general I think it's probably better in a case like this for you to outline your proof in the question, so people know what type of answer you would like (and what you wouldn't like). See here

How these pairs were found?

By brute force. Similarly applying brute force to these numbers gives $738$ different fibres of size $2$, as well as one of size $3$: the fibre of $117660$, which is ${2220, 3180, 7844}$. Can you please at least sketch the idea of your answer? Is it also brute force?

Yes. I use brute force too.

Do what it says: "Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc."

$f(n)$ is so irregular as a function of $n$ that I'm not surprised if there's no better way to find examples of $af(a)=bf(b)$ than just doing a search.

This does suggest the question: "is this function eventually injective", ie is there some $N$ such that it's injective on ${N, N + 1, N + 2, \dotsc}$? This might be more interesting, since failure of injectivity for small values can just be due to "randomness". I don't know much about $f(n)$ but I think it's possible that that question is very very hard or impossible to answer, though.

Let $p$ a prime number greater than 6.
$$(5 | (p-2)) \lor (5|(p-3)) \implies (2p^{2}) \cdot f(2p^{2}) = (5p^{2}) \cdot f(5p^{2})$$
Then $n \cdot f(n)$ is not an injective function. There are infinitely many counterexamples.

$$3048360737858 \cdot f(3048360737858) = 7620901844645 \cdot f(7620901844645)$$

It would likely be of help to future Readers to sketch or reference a proof of this result.  It appears to give a strong resolution of your Question as asked, but I don't know how to prove it.

The computation that $f(2p^2) = 5$ can be found in this older Question.  If I understand correctly, that leaves only $f(5p^2) = 2$ to be shown, which I suspect is because we have just the two abelian cases.

There are general methods to find the number of groups of $f(pq^{2})$ here and here. You are correct. $f(2p^{2})=5$ :)

If $p=3$, the equality also holds. My answer don't is showing that all possible solutions have that form.
